# Where can I find the list of gossip menu icons?

Tags: azerothcore

I'm making a c++ script and would like to add good looking icons to the gossip menu entries.

Where can I find the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gossip list is available in the [GossipDef.h](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/src/server/game/Entities/Creature/GossipDef.h#L19) file:

```
enum GossipOptionIcon
{
    GOSSIP_ICON_CHAT       = 0,  // white chat bubble
    GOSSIP_ICON_VENDOR     = 1,  // brown bag
    GOSSIP_ICON_TAXI       = 2,  // flightmarker (paperplane)
    GOSSIP_ICON_TRAINER    = 3,  // brown book (trainer)
    GOSSIP_ICON_INTERACT_1 = 4,  // golden interaction wheel
    GOSSIP_ICON_INTERACT_2 = 5,  // golden interaction wheel
    GOSSIP_ICON_MONEY_BAG  = 6,  // brown bag (with gold coin in lower corner)
    GOSSIP_ICON_TALK       = 7,  // white chat bubble (with "..." inside)
    GOSSIP_ICON_TABARD     = 8,  // white tabard
    GOSSIP_ICON_BATTLE     = 9,  // two crossed swords
    GOSSIP_ICON_DOT        = 10, // yellow dot/point
    GOSSIP_ICON_CHAT_11    = 11, // white chat bubble
    GOSSIP_ICON_CHAT_12    = 12, // white chat bubble
    GOSSIP_ICON_CHAT_13    = 13, // white chat bubble
    GOSSIP_ICON_UNK_14     = 14, // INVALID - DO NOT USE
    GOSSIP_ICON_UNK_15     = 15, // INVALID - DO NOT USE
    GOSSIP_ICON_CHAT_16    = 16, // white chat bubble
    GOSSIP_ICON_CHAT_17    = 17, // white chat bubble
    GOSSIP_ICON_CHAT_18    = 18, // white chat bubble
    GOSSIP_ICON_CHAT_19    = 19, // white chat bubble
    GOSSIP_ICON_CHAT_20    = 20, // white chat bubble
    GOSSIP_ICON_MAX
};
```

Here is also an available list on the web wiki:

http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/gossip_menu_option#optionicon